# которой передается массив и число и возвращает массив первого и последнего индексов этого числа. Если массив пуст, верните [-1, -1]

Tags: javascript, массивы

Функция, которой передается массив и число и возвращает массив первого и последнего индексов этого числа. Если массив пуст, верните [-1, -1] помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function f (arr, n) {
    return [arr.indexOf(n), arr.lastIndexOf(n)]
}

console.log(f([1, 10, 4, 7, 12, 7, 19], 7))
console.log(f([], 7))
```